# Book suggestion- complex analysis -conformal mapping.

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-numbers, book-recommendation, conformal-geometry

I am studying complex analysis. And I am using J. Bak and D.J. Newman's book.(springer) And now my studying topic is conformal map. In addition to this book, I want to learn other book names which explains this topic more clearly  and suggested book's content should be parallel to that of my using book. And this book sould contain more examples as well. Thank you for your suggestions:)

Comment: What book are you actually using?

Comment: I said above in the first line. @andrew

Comment: That's not a title or author

Comment: Auw sorry, I wrote false. I corrected now! Sorry. @andrew

Comment: Can you suggest any book name, which I can learn well? @andrew

Answer (score 2):

I have found this book: Flanigan "Complex Variables" to be excellent, especially if you are studying on your own. I also am self-taught and love this book.

[http://www.amazon.com/Complex-Variables-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486613887/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1382820565&sr=1-1&keywords=flanigan+complex](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486613887)

I am not sure how advanced you are and how confident you feel about what you have studied. However, beginning with Chapter 3, you can get excellent, clear, detailed explanations of the material. Additionally, what I especially like about this book is that it has many pictures so you can really see what is going on.

In that it is the Dover edition of a classic, it is not expensive - especially compared to the outrageous prices of other books.

Comment: Thank you very much, I Will look at it:))

Comment: You are welcome. Best of luck.

Comment: @B11b On a more advanced level, this is an excellent book: Ablowitz and Fokas http://www.amazon.com/Complex-Variables-Introduction-Applications-Mathematics/dp/0521534291

Comment: Yes Dear @Andrew I looked at both. And the second one is better and more understandable for me:)

Comment: @B11b Glad to hear that. Books are so personal, especially when you are studying on your own. Best regards,

Comment: Of course! agree with you:) thanks, best... Dear @Andrew :)